# modify function for local HTML code

Tags: javascript

I have function that works perfect, but not for my scope:

```
function _svgToCanvas() {
    var nodesToRecover = [];
    var nodesToRemove = [];

    var svgElems = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');

    for (var i = 0; i < svgElems.length; i++) {
        var node = svgElems[i];
        var parentNode = node.parentNode;
        var svg = parentNode.innerHTML;

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvg(canvas, svg);

        nodesToRecover.push({
            parent: parentNode,
            child: node
        });
        parentNode.removeChild(node);

        nodesToRemove.push({
            parent: parentNode,
            child: canvas
        });

        parentNode.appendChild(canvas);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to modify it for using local code that comes from param, like this:

```
function _svgToCanvas(content) {
    var nodesToRecover = [];
    var nodesToRemove = [];

    var svgElems = content.getElementsByTagName('svg');

    for (var i = 0; i < svgElems.length; i++) {

    }
    return content;
}

var content = $('#main_contents').get(0); 
result = _svgToCanvas(content);
```

But I can't modify the `for` loop. How to modify it?

Comment: What should be the role of `content`? Who should it replace in the original loop?

Comment: need html code for generation pdf file var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
    var content = $('#main_contents').get(0); 
    var result = _svgToCanvas(content);
    pdf.addHTML(content, function() {
        pdf.save("caravan.pdf");
    });

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "var svg = parentNode.innerHTML;" doesn't give you the correct parameter for function canvg.

This piece of code comes from canvg.js, try it.

```
function _svgToCanvas(content) {
    var svgTags = content.querySelectorAll('svg');
    for (var i=0; i<svgTags.length; i++) {
        var svgTag = svgTags[i];
        var c = document.createElement('canvas');
        c.width = svgTag.clientWidth;
        c.height = svgTag.clientHeight;
        svgTag.parentNode.insertBefore(c, svgTag);
        svgTag.parentNode.removeChild(svgTag);
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(svgTag);
        canvg(c, div.innerHTML);
    }    
    return content;    
}
```

This funtion will not change the original content, and just return a new dom node.

```
function _svgToCanvas(content) {
     var newContent = content.cloneNode(true);
     var svgTags = newContent.querySelectorAll('svg');
     var svgTagsOriginal = content.querySelectorAll('svg');
     for (var i=0; i<svgTags.length; i++) {
         var svgTag = svgTags[i];
         var svgTagOriginal = svgTagsOriginal[i];
         var c = document.createElement('canvas');
         c.width = svgTagOriginal.clientWidth;
         c.height = svgTagOriginal.clientHeight;
         svgTag.parentNode.insertBefore(c, svgTag);
         svgTag.parentNode.removeChild(svgTag);
         content.appendChild(c);
         var div = document.createElement('div');
         div.appendChild(svgTag);
         canvg(c, div.innerHTML);
     }

     return newContent;     
}
```

Comment: it works fine, but i wont to this function not chagne my html page in browser and just change value of variable "content". or it is not possible?

Comment: You must clone the content node from your HTML page

Comment: var content = $('#main_contents').get(0).cloneNode(true);  
result = _svgToCanvas(content);

Comment: it is not change the original content, but not working. Error msg: "Uncaught Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG"

Comment: Could you try var content = $('#main_contents').get(0); result = _svgToCanvas(content);  and the _svgToCanvas is the function which has  the variable svgTagOriginal ?